# Calling a function that has a TypeAlias as a parameter?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, closures

So I've written a little practice program that has to do with closures. I'm trying to better understand how the asynchronous concept works. When I try to call `request()`, I get conversion errors as seen below:

```
import UIKit

let correctPasscode = "3EyX"

typealias CompletionHandler = (result: AnyObject?, error: String?) -> Void

func request(passcode: String, completionHandler: CompletionHandler) {

sendBackRequest(passcode) {(result, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
    }
    else {
        print(result)

    }}

}

func sendBackRequest(passCode: String, completionHandler: CompletionHandler) {
if passCode == correctPasscode {
    completionHandler(result: "Correct. Please proceed", error: nil)

} else {
    completionHandler(result: nil, error: "There was an error signing in")

}
}


request(correctPasscode, completionHandler: CompletionHandler) // Error happens here
```

[image]

Comment: Please share your code, not an image of it

Comment: Sorry about that, just made the edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type alias is there to tell you what *actual* type you need to pass. In this case, the type is a *closure* of type

```
(result: AnyObject?, error: String?) -> Void
```

You pass it like this:

```
request(correctPasscode, completionHandler:{
    (result: AnyObject?, error: String?) in 
    print("Inside the handler...")
    // Do some useful things here
})
```

or even shorter -

```
request(correctPasscode) {
    (result: AnyObject?, error: String?) in 
    print("Inside the handler...")
    // Do some useful things here
}
```

or even shorter - (the types are known via the func declaration) -

```
request(correctPasscode) { result, error in
    print("Inside the handler...")
    // Do some useful things here
}
```

Comment: Or just can omit the `completionHandler` parameter in the call of the trailing closure.

Comment: @VictorSigler Right. Thanks!

Comment: I get an error when I try to call request to do what the program should do. Error: Consecutive statements on a line mustbe separated by ';'. I basically copy and pasted the code that you told me to use to pass my parameters in request(). Maybe I'm misunderstanding the way closures work?

Comment: @snapchatdotcom I missed parentheses in the code. Please try it again.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You're welcome.I edit your answer to fix the problem of the parentheses in the parameters in the closure, just a minor fix. I'm just impressed with your profile wow!!! Gold badge in almost every strong programming language, :)

Comment: @VictorSigler Thanks! That's what happens when you take a job and learn the language as you go. Learning Prolog while on the job was the hardest, because it did not look like anything else :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you try to accomplish, but this line:

```
request(correctPasscode, completionHandler: CompletionHandler)
```

doesn't compile because you are not passing a `CompletionHandler` closure to the function but rather a *type* object representing the type of that completion handler.

Hence the error: `Cannot convert value of 'CompletionHandler.*Type*'`.

A valid call would be:

```
request(correctPasscode) { result, error in
  print("result was \(result), and error was \(error)")
}
```

But then your `request` function doesn't do anything with the closure which is passed in. It is a little hard to say what you want ...

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. All I'm doing is sending this "Correct Passcode" to this function sendBackRequest to let me know whether or not the passcode was correct (I made it the correct passcode because I assigned that a variable which I passed in).

Comment: I can see that, but why do you wrap `sendBackRequest` in yet another `request` function? You are already passing a closure to `sendBackRequest` within `request`. What is the purpose of the (unused) `completionHandler` argument of `request`?